# MYSQL : Return rows if Dates not found in subquery

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

The following query gives an output of records if there is a corresponding datewise  record in taameer_pay_details table. If there are no corresponding records, the query hides the fund name from the fund_type_master

```
select Revenue as Revenue,
cur_date as Date,
rec_no as FirstRecNo,
Cash as cash, 
cheque as cheque, 
sum(Cash+ cheque) as Total
from (SELECT  
ft.fund_type as Revenue,STR_TO_DATE(tpd.paid_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as cur_date,tpd.rec_no as rec_no,sum(if(tpd.pay_mode='C',tpd.paid_amt,0)) as Cash,sum(if(tpd.pay_mode='DD',tpd.paid_amt,0)) as cheque
FROM taameer_details fd

JOIN taameer_pay_details tpd 
on tpd.tpay_id=fd.tamDet_id 
cross join fund_type_master ft 
on fd.fund_type =ft.fund_id
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY , STR_TO_DATE(tpd.paid_date, '%d-%m-%Y') ,'2015-02-02') >=0  
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY ,'2015-01-01',STR_TO_DATE(tpd.paid_date, '%d-%m-%Y') ) >=0 
AND tpd.pay_type=2 
AND tpd.status=1 
group by ft.fund_id) a 
group by Revenue
```

Expected Output

```
Revenue         Date    FirstRecNo  cash    cheque  Total           
General Funds   2015-01-16  0       46100   7800    53900
Voluntary       2015-01-16  0       0       0       0
XYz             2015-01-16  0       0       0       0
Muv             2015-01-16  0       0       0       0
HMjwa           2015-01-16  0       0       900     900
NJUMz           2015-01-16  0       0       0       0
S Unit          2015-01-16  0       251     0       251
```

Current Output

```
Revenue         Date    FirstRecNo  cash    cheque  Total           
General Funds   2015-01-16  0       46100   7800    53900
NJUMz           2015-01-16  0       0       900     900
S Unit          2015-01-16  0       251     0       251
```

Please help me re-write the query in order to output the data as per the expected result.

Comment: It is not quite obvious to me how you want your row to be grouped together. Maybe you could reduce that to some [simple (but complete) example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Plz share table schema??

Answer (score 0):

Try using an outer join:

```
FROM taameer_details fd 
LEFT OUTER JOIN taameer_pay_details tpd
```

You should also include all the conditions for the joined table taameer_pay_details on the "on clause" of the outer join:

```
FROM taamer_details fd
LEFT OUTER JOIN taameer_pay_details tpd
ON tpd.tpay_id=fd.tamDet_id
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY , STR_TO_DATE(tpd.paid_date, '%d-%m-%Y') ,'2015-02-02') >=0
AND ...
```